# TestComplete - Incorrect Cross Reference Error

Tags: testing, automated-tests, jscript, testcomplete

I am using TestComplete 11 with JScript code in the scripts - no keyword tests.

I am getting a cross reference error that is incorrect.  I checked all the USEUNIT declarations of the referenced units and they do NOT reference each other, yet I am all of the sudden getting this error.

EX:

```
Unit DataCheck:
//USEUNIT Button
//USEUNIT Lots of other Units

Unit Button
//USEUNIT Input
//USEUNIT Map
//USEUNIT Utilities
```

ERROR: 
Syntax error(s)
The units Button and DataCheck refer to each other. 
Cross references are not allowed in JScript units.

Error locationL
Unit: "Button"
Line 4 Column: 1

Ummm.....line 4 has NO DATA!  *SIGROWL*

Remove Utilities from Button and no error, but then a function essential to Button can't be accessed.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the Utilities unit references the DataCheck unit:
**Utilities** -> DataCheck -> Button -> **Utilities**

It is also possible that there are more units in this chain:
**Utilities** -> [Mysterious Unit A] -> [Mysterious Unit B] -> DataCheck -> Button -> **Utilities**

Check the entire reference chain.

Also, you can consider using [Script Extensions](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/69987/) for library code.

Comment: Ok.  I am having some trouble wrapping my head around this concept.  I found the offending function in a completely different Unit.  If I move it to DataCheck, no error.  If I move it to any other Unit and add a reference to DataCheck, error.  So, if I understand correctly, the references that flow Utilities > ExButton > DataCheck > Button > Utilities is the issue???  (ExButton being the original location of offending function)

Comment: Yes, this is a clear circular reference situation. To avoid it, you need to have library units (e.g. Utilities in your case) that do not reference any other units. If you have some constants or constructs that belongs to a specific unit (e.g. A) and should be used by the Utilities unit, you need to move these constants/constructs to a new unit without any references (e.g. A_Utils) and reference it from both A and Utilities unit. This is a quite common situation and, for example, in C++ you are facing the same behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!